# AngularJS form submitting when it's not supposed to and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filereader

I'm trying to create an AngularJS form. One part of the form is taking the Base64 from a file and storing it to my `$scope.user`. However, clicking a file upload input and selecting my file is submitting my form, which should not be happening.

Here's my form:

```
<form ng-submit="processForm()" name="merchApp"  style="position:relative">
    <div class="form-section" ui-view>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">


        <button href="#" ng-click='docUpload("userId")'>Upload File</button>&nbsp;{{user.uploadIdName}}
        <br/>* Accepted file types: .jpg, .png, .gif, .pdf, .doc, .docx
        <br/>
        (Max file size: 2MB)
        <br/>
        <input ng-model="user.uploadId" type="hidden" value="{{user.uploadId}}" required>


    <br/><br/>
    <button type="submit" class="next" ng-disabled="merchApp.$invalid">SUBMIT APPLICATION</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>   
</form>
```

Here's my `app.js`

```
.controller('formController', ['$scope', '$http', '$parse', function($scope, $http, $parse) {

// we will store all of our form data in this object
$scope.user = {};

$scope.docUpload = function() { //default function, to be override if browser supports input type='file'
  $scope.data.alert = "Your browser doesn't support HTML5 input type='File'"
}


var fileUploadScope;
var fileSelect = document.createElement('input'); //input it's not displayed in html, I want to trigger it form other elements
fileSelect.type = 'file';

if (fileSelect.disabled) { //check if browser support input type='file' and stop execution of controller
  return;
}
var fileUploadScope;
var fileUploadName;
$scope.docUpload = function(x) { //activate function to begin input file on click
    switch(x){
        case "checkBankLetter":
            fileUploadScope = $parse("uploadCheckBankLetter");
            fileUploadName = $parse("uploadCheckBankLetterFileName");
            break;
        case "userId":
            fileUploadScope = $parse("uploadId");
            fileUploadName = $parse("uploadIdName");
            break;
        default:
            alert ("error");
    }


    fileSelect.click();
}

fileSelect.onchange = function() { //set callback to action after choosing file

     var f = fileSelect.files[0];
     var fsize = f.size;
     var fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'gif'];

    if (fsize > 2097152){//file size limit is 2MB
           alert ("File size too large. Please select a file 2MB or smaller.");
     }
     else {// file size is acceptable
         if(f){
             var extension = f.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),  //file extension from input file
                 isSuccess = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;  //is extension in acceptable types

             if (isSuccess) { //yes
                var r = new FileReader();
                r.fileName = f.name;
                if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined"){

                        r.onloadend = function(e) { //callback after files finish loading
                            // allow for different scope names for file upload functions
                            fileUploadScope.assign($scope.user, e.target.result);
                            fileUploadName.assign($scope.user, r.fileName);

                            $scope.$apply();


                        //here you can send data over your server as desired
                        }
                        r.readAsDataURL(f); //once defined all callbacks, begin reading the file


                }



             }
             else {
                 alert("Please select an acceptable file type");
             }
         }
     } 




};

// function to process the form
$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'docusign.php',
      data    : $scope.user  // pass in data as strings

     })
      .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            location.replace(data);
        });
};
}])
```

`processForm()` is firing after I click `<button href="#" ng-click='docUpload("userId")'>Upload File</button>` and select a file, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: when you select the file for upload are you clicking it or hitting enter from the file select?  If you are hitting enter, it could be the form interprets that as the default submission event?

Comment: I'm clicking it, then I'm hitting "Open" from the Windows file explorer that pops up.

Comment: Have you tried changing the input type to "file"?  Any reason why you're using "hidden"?  When I've made a file upload UI, I've always used "file".

Comment: I need to get the base64 of the file and store it in $scope.user. If that's not the best way to do it, do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally it is better practice to specify `type` attribute for buttons.

button without `type` attribute acts as submit buttons that is reason your form getting submitted when you click on button.

So add `type` attribute to button.| `type="button"`
remove `href` attribute since it is unnecessary for button.

Change this line
`<button href="#" ng-click='docUpload("userId")'>Upload File</button>`
to
`<button type="button" ng-click='docUpload("userId")'>Upload File</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is best practices, but I was able to fix my problem by adding `onclick="return false"` to my input button.

Comment: you can do in that way also. see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42678167/3543808)